# How to access cross region Glue database in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

My Redshift is in us-east1 and the Glue database is in us-west2 region, when I create external schema in Redshift to point into Glue database, the list of tables in external schema is empty,
It seems I have to create VPC peering and configure routing tables, I'm not a network expert, wondering if there is any other easier way to access a Glue database from other region in Redshift?